# compare previous value in each loop with current value

Tags: express, pug

i have a json that i have to itterate in my jade :

```
[

{ RefSlipNo: 
   { fieldlabel: 'RefSlipNo',
     fieldname: 'RefSlipNo',
     fieldtype: 'text',
     required: '1',
     default_value: '',
     placeholder: 'Ref Slip No',
     order_no: '1',
     formgroup: 'vehicleDetails',
     can_delete: '0',
     status: '1' },
  BookNumber: 
   { fieldlabel: 'BookNumber',
     fieldname: 'BookNumber',
     fieldtype: 'text',
     required: '1',
     default_value: '',
     placeholder: 'Book Number',
     order_no: '2',
     formgroup: 'vehicleDetails',
     can_delete: '1',
     status: '1' },
  SlipDate: 
   { fieldlabel: 'SlipDate',
     fieldname: 'SlipDate',
     fieldtype: 'text',
     required: '1',
     default_value: '',
     placeholder: 'Slip Date',
     order_no: '3',
     formgroup: 'invoice',
     can_delete: '1',
     status: '1' },
  FillFuelDate: 
   { fieldlabel: 'FillFuelDate',
     fieldname: 'FillFuelDate',
     fieldtype: 'text',
     required: '1',
     default_value: '',
     placeholder: 'Fill Fuel Date',
     order_no: '4',
     formgroup: 'invoice',
     can_delete: '1',
     status: '1' }
]
```

i want to use fieldset and  legend on the basis of formgroup like:

```
-------invoice--------------------|
FillFuelDate :                    |
SlipDate :                        |
----------------------------------|

-------vehicleDetails-------------|
RefSlipNo :                       |
BookNumber :                      |
----------------------------------|
```

But could not able to get logic. How to loop it in jade. I want to get all field list with invoice formgroup under one fieldset and all vehicledetails under 1 fieldset as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript, define a function like this, and pass it as a local to your pug template:

```
function groupByFormGroup(fields) {
  const formGroups = [];
  const formGroupsByName = {};
  fields.forEach(field => {
    if (!formGroupsByName[field.formGroup]) {
      formGroupsByName[field.formGroup] = {name: field.formGroup, fields: []};
      formGroups.push(formGroupsByName);
    }
    formGroupsByName[field.formGroup].push(field);
  });
}
```

Then in the pug template, do something like:

```
each formGroup in groupByFormGroup(fields)
  fieldset
    legend= formGroup.name
    each field in formGroup.fields
      label= field.fieldLabel
      input(type="text" name=field.fieldName)
```